# Meaning of あれこれ and あちらこちら

Tags: meaning, words

What is the meaning of あれこれ and あちらこちら? Are both describe thing that plural? Or just 'here and there' and 'these and that' ?

Comment: What does your dictionary say about the meaning of these words?

Answer (score 1):

It means this and that.

For example:

- What have you been doing lately? (最近　何をしているか）
- Well, this and that. (さあ、あれこれ)

Remember that これ,それ and あれ are used as position pronouns.

Comment: But but iv had searched at dictionary.goo.ne.jp, and means of あれこれ is 'いろいろ' and あちらこちら is '様々な場所と方向' . its confusing . Do you think あれこれ and あちらこちら is classified to reduplication?

Comment: あちら is the more polite version of あれ, likewise こちら with これ. So i believe that they have the meaning but are used in different situations.

Comment: but こちら is often used as a location such as in the phrase こちらへどうぞ meaning "this way, please". as far as the less formal of あちらこちら I would be more likely to believe it to be あっちこっち which has the meaning of "here and there (and everywhere)". あれこれ definitely has less of a feel of going to different places and more with doing one thing then another then another, etc., i.e. switching tasks however menial, or in other contexts, dealing with different objects.